# Drawing a line depending on user input

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, drawing, user-input

I have the following problem regarding the usage of PyQt5:
I created a GUI with a label (which is a png - map with stations that are connected via blue and green lines), a textEdit and a pushButton in QtDesigner and PyQt5.

[image]

Now, I would like to enter a number between 1 and 4 into the textEdit. Depending on the user input, parts of the blue line in the attached image should be drawn in red.

I guess an **example** explains it better: If the user input in the TextEdit is 2 and the pushButton is clicked, the blue line from S1 to S3 shall be drawn in red. If the user input in the TextEdit is 1 and the pushButton is clicked again, the blue line from S1 to S2 shall be drawn in red, so the red line from S2 to S3 shall be blue again.

**mapDrawer.py**

```
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
import sys


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()  # Call the inherited classes __init__ method
        uic.loadUi('DesignerGUI.ui', self)  # Load the .ui file
        self.setWindowTitle("GUI for user defined track drawing")

        pixmap = QPixmap('mapRail.png')
        self.pic_label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.pic_label.setScaledContents(True)

        self.show()  # Show the GUI


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**DesignerGUI.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>577</width>
    <height>347</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
      <item>
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeType">
         <enum>QSizePolicy::Fixed</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>5</width>
          <height>30</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Fixed">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>0</width>
          <height>30</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="font">
         <font>
          <pointsize>12</pointsize>
         </font>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; color:#0055ff;&quot;&gt;Blue Line&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QTextEdit" name="textEdit">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>0</width>
          <height>0</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="maximumSize">
         <size>
          <width>11515151</width>
          <height>30</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="font">
         <font>
          <pointsize>12</pointsize>
         </font>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Fixed">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>0</width>
          <height>30</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="font">
         <font>
          <pointsize>12</pointsize>
         </font>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>PushButton</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_2">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeType">
         <enum>QSizePolicy::Fixed</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>5</width>
          <height>30</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="pic_label">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="minimumSize">
       <size>
        <width>183</width>
        <height>50</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="maximumSize">
       <size>
        <width>1460</width>
        <height>400</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>TextLabel</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>577</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Will the image be always the same? If not, how are those images created?

Comment: The shown example is very simplified. In the final GUI I imagine to have several maps that have much more stations and lines as in the example. The unchanged images/maps are given to the user - not part of the GUI. 

I mean I could also produce lots of pictures that cover all possible user inputs, but this would lead to a lot of pictures (large data volume) and is a lot of manual work. I just thought there was a way to automate this a bit.

Comment: There may be several possible approaches to your question, it all depends on how those circuits are managed or created. If there's a way to access the graphical objects (shape, position, colors) and, most importantly, have a reference to those that you need to change, you could use a custom widget and overwrite the `paintEvent` to paint the circuits by yourself. If they're svg (and their internal structure allows it), it's possible that you could open them and change the colors (it would be trickier, though). But if they're plain raster images, you've no other option than create all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a .png to display your network, it's probably easiest to create separate .png's, one for each option, and change the pixmap accordingly. Consider for example the following four images which I've saved as "squares0.png" to "squares3.png".

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

To change the displayed pixmap when the button is pressed, you could then do something like

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()  # Call the inherited classes __init__ method
        uic.loadUi('laser.ui', self)  # Load the .ui file
        self.setWindowTitle("GUI for user defined track drawing")
        self.pixmaps = {'1':'squares1.png', '2':'squares2.png', '3':'squares3.png'}
        self.default_pixmap = 'squares0.png'
        self.pic_label.setScaledContents(True)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.set_pixmap)
        self.set_pixmap()

        self.show()  # Show the GUI

    def set_pixmap(self, strng = ''):
        text = self.textEdit.toPlainText().strip()
        file = self.pixmaps.get(text, self.default_pixmap)
        pixmap = QPixmap(file)
        self.pic_label.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

[image]

By the way, for a more user-friendly experience you could consider using a `QSpinBox` or a `QComboBox` instead of a `QTextEdit` for entering the numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much for the proposed solution and the advice regarding user-friendliness.
I was also thinking about this kind of solution. Unfortunately a lot of manual work when considering a lot of maps and possibilities. But anyway this would work :), maybe there is antother way?